# Masonry layout with CSS - How to make div not break

Tags: html, css

My html is like this

```css
.head-heading {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #525659;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.divsection .col-md-4 {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
.contact-smaldiv {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0px;
}

.contact-smaldiv h1, .contact-smaldiv h2, .contact-smaldiv h3, .contact-smaldiv h4 {
    color: #ef9c00;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif !important;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0;
}
h1.contact-name, h2.contact-name, h3.contact-name, h4.contact-name {
    color: #16100f;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin: 0px 0 6px 0;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
}
.contact-smaldiv p {
    margin: 2px 0 3px 0;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    color: #414042;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'AkzidenzGrotesk-Medium';
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.divsection { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.col-md-4 { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <h1 class="head-heading">What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    <div class="divsection">
       
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                <!-- starts of info-->
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="add-heading">
                            Why do we use it?
                        </h1>
                        <h4 class="contact-name"></h4>
                        <p>
                            <label>No:</label>
                            375 9777
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <a href="mailto:dfdjff@gmail.com">
                                ddfdjff@gmail.com
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of info-->
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                Where does it come from?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>Phone:</label>
                                052794959
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                724 455
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:d@dummy.com">
                                    d@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                Where can I get some?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Second name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>gfjgjf:</label>
                                375 9720
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                4545464
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:j@dummy.com">
                                    j@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:t@dummy.com">
                                    t@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                1914 translation by H. Rackham
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                charity
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>DDI:</label>
                                375 9715
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                221952
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto: r@dummy.com">
                                    r@dummy.com
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Coming Soon
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                               What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                               Lorem Ipsum
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>I:</label>
                               3759723
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>C:</label>
                               2330079
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:s@dummy.com">
                                    s@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                My name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>D:</label>
                              3759727
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>C:</label>
                                914844
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:b@dummy.com">
                                    b@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
                <!-- col md end-->
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my first column third Div is breaking in to two, and occupying first and second column, i don't want this behaviour, if there is no space to occuppy that `col-md-4` element I want it to go to next column completely, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float` from the bricks. That's overwriting the `display: inline-block` because floating an element makes it `block`

```css
.head-heading {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #525659;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.divsection .col-md-4 {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
.contact-smaldiv {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0px;
}

.contact-smaldiv h1, .contact-smaldiv h2, .contact-smaldiv h3, .contact-smaldiv h4 {
    color: #ef9c00;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif !important;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0;
}
h1.contact-name, h2.contact-name, h3.contact-name, h4.contact-name {
    color: #16100f;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin: 0px 0 6px 0;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
}
.contact-smaldiv p {
    margin: 2px 0 3px 0;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    color: #414042;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'AkzidenzGrotesk-Medium';
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.divsection { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.col-md-4 { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <h1 class="head-heading">What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    <div class="divsection">
       
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                <!-- starts of info-->
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="add-heading">
                            Why do we use it?
                        </h1>
                        <h4 class="contact-name"></h4>
                        <p>
                            <label>No:</label>
                            375 9777
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <a href="mailto:dfdjff@gmail.com">
                                ddfdjff@gmail.com
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of info-->
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                Where does it come from?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>Phone:</label>
                                052794959
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                724 455
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:d@dummy.com">
                                    d@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                Where can I get some?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Second name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>gfjgjf:</label>
                                375 9720
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                4545464
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:j@dummy.com">
                                    j@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:t@dummy.com">
                                    t@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                1914 translation by H. Rackham
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                charity
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>DDI:</label>
                                375 9715
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Cell:</label>
                                221952
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto: r@dummy.com">
                                    r@dummy.com
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                Coming Soon
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                               What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                               Lorem Ipsum
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>I:</label>
                               3759723
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>C:</label>
                               2330079
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:s@dummy.com">
                                    s@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col md end-->

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contact-smaldiv">
                    <!-- starts of info-->
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="add-heading">
                                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                            </h1>
                            <h4 class="contact-name">
                                My name
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <label>D:</label>
                              3759727
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>C:</label>
                                914844
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>id:</label>
                                <a href="mailto:b@dummy.com">
                                    b@dummy.com
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of info-->
                </div>
                <!-- col md end-->
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks, But What i expected was first column will take 3 rows and rest divided in to rest of the columns, Is there any way to set height for the container and make this happen? or any other way? i tried giving height to container, but not taking

Comment: @Athul I don't know, I don't think you can do that. Altering the height wouldn't do anything, the browser calculates the best layout. You could always just make 3 columns with normal elements and put however many rows in each column that you want.